# Check email before submitting is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

How I can check if e mail is already taken? I found a script but it displaying only "checking.." and I can not get the exact result if email exist. below you have the code:

```
<span id="usernamestatus"></span> 
<input type="text" onblur="checkusername()" id="sign_up_email_input_first" name="email_sign_up" placeholder="E-Mail">

        function checkusername() {
                var status = document.getElementById("usernamestatus");
                var u = document.getElementById("sign_up_email_input_first").value;
                if ( u !="") {
                    status.innerHTML = 'checking...';
                    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    hr.open("POST", "name_check.php", true);
                    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlendcoded");
                    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status ==200) {
                            status.innerHTML = hr.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    var v = "name2check="+u;
                    hr.send(v);
                }
            }
```

**name_check.php**

```
    if(isset($_POST['sign_up_email_input_first']) && $_POST['sign_up_email_input_first'] != "") {
        $username = $_POST['sign_up_email_input_first'];
        $sql_name_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$username' LIMIT 1");
        $uname_check= mysql_num_rows($sql_name_check);
        if(strlen($username)<4){
            echo "You have invalid e mial adress";
            exit();
        }
        if($uname_check <1){
            echo "<strong>". $username. "</strong> Is OK";
            exit();
        }else{
            echo "<strong>" .$username. "</strong> is taken!";
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How *specifically* is this code not working as expected?  When you step through in a debugger, where exactly does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  What are the runtime values when that happens?  Note also that this code is *wide open* to **SQL injection**, so you could literally be executing *anything* in your database.  You're also not checking for errors, which you should always do after executing a database query.  The database *might* be trying to tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP file , replace

```
$_POST['sign_up_email_input_first']
```

with:

```
$_POST['email_sign_up']
```

You basically grab values with names and not id's